# position absolute добавляет скролл по x

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть менюшка, которая должна раскрываться, но при раскрывании появляется боковой скролл у родителя, а не менюшка раскрывается поверх

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хотелось бы что-то типа такого, чтоб не было этого бокового скрола

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на хостинг, на котором находится данный блок - http://test.utjhubla.beget.tech/
Вроде кажется легким, но у меня не получается понять причину

Буду благодарен за помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

Не сильно понял причину, но мешал - overflow-x: hidden, вроде по горизонтали обрезалось, а по вертикали - нет, но все же, убрал - и работает нормально